# FancyBox "swapTheImage" Function: Clicking on Images in Carousel Refreshes Page to Configurable Product

Tags: javascript, product-images, troubleshooting

As the title states, when trying to click an additional product image for a configurable/simple product, the page instead reloads and reverts back to the configurable product page. You can see this at: http://abbietest.hotmakeup.com/v04/lips/lip-gloss/glistening-gloss-product

I've enabled the additional images for the linked product for the first two swatch options.

The client's live version of the site uses the same FancyBox lightbox — it is included with Amasty's Color Swatch Pro extension that we are using — it functions properly on the main domain at hotmakeup.com.

The following are error messages we get when the function is called and executed. The bottom half appears right before the page reloads. [image]

The error messages from the console above refers to a cached javascript file at: `media/js/ad6ced663bf0f0132dd7f7102f03a15d.js`.

But the source of the function seems to be at: `skin/frontend/base/default/js/amasty/amconf/zoomer.js`

We've compared zoomer.js from the abbietest subdomain to the zoomer.js at the main domain and they're identical — so we're having trouble isolating the issue.

On the subdomain, the class value of "active" does get inserted — this can be seen before the page reloads when inspecting the element. But something is causing the page to redirect.

The screenshot above also happens to have an ebiz error. We've tried disabling that module through the Magento backend in case it was conflicting with FancyBox/zoomer.js but it made no difference. Any other troubleshooting ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to clear the cache? all the bocks and JS cache??

Comment: Yes, both through Magento's refresh management and manually clearing out the JS cache folder.

Comment: are you able to turn off the js aggregation on the sub site in `system > configuration > advanced > developer > JavaScript Settings` then `Merge JavaScript Files` to `No`

Answer (score 1):

If you Inspect Element the carousel I noticed that the **href** on hotmakeup.com is defined but the **href** on abbietest.hotmakeup.com is not. Could this be the issue? I'm not sure how you would define the **href** but maybe someone else will know.